# Clarification on Protobuf PrintField()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm trying to use the Google Protobuf API found [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/toc-everything) and I'm having trouble with the built in PrintField() method with the following info:

> PrintField(field, value, out, indent=0, as_utf8=False, as_one_line=False)
>
> Print a single field name/value pair. For repeated fields, the value should be a single element.

After merging my message, I'm able to print out the fully merged layout. However, I'd like the specific field/value pair and I'm a bit unsure how to go about doing that as I can't find any full fledged internet examples.

I have tried the following:

proto.PrintField(1, 1,  cStringIO.StringIO())
, proto.PrintField('field1', 'subfield',  cStringIO.StringIO())

> Where my message looks like:
>   message field1 {subfield = 1;}

Running as such yields the following error: "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_extension'" this is the same in both cases, the only change being 'int' or 'string'.